# How to make typescript infer response type based on response's property (ex: "type")

Tags: typescript

I was trying to create a function that returns an object with a "type" property that'll determine the type of response (Either TResA or TResB)

Basically this:

```js
enum SYSTEM_TYPE {
A = 1, 
B = 2
}
export interface IResCommon {
   type: SYSTEM_TYPE;
}
export type TResA = {
   name: string;
} & IResCommon;
export type TResB = {
  age: number;
} & IResCommon;

export type TResAll = TResA | TResB;



// Don't know how to apply this: 
export type TResCondition<T extends TResA & TResB> = T['type'] extends SYSTEM_TYPE.A ? TResA : TResB;

function run():TResAll /*TResCondition<T>*/{
   const math = Math.floor(Math.random()*2) + 1;
   if (math === SYSTEM_TYPE.A) {
     return { name: "foo", type: SYSTEM_TYPE.A}
   } else {
     return { age: 12, type: SYSTEM_TYPE.B}
   }
}

var o = run()
if (o.type === SYSTEM_TYPE.A) {
     // Should assume o as type TResA
   console.log(o.name) //<--- Property 'name' does not exist on type 'TResAll'
} else {
     // Should assume o as type TResB
   console.log(o.age) // Property 'age' does not exist on type 'TResAll'
}
```

How can I correctly apply `TResCondition` in order to avoid property 'X' is undefined after checking the value of o.type?

Here's a link to the typescript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygmjAKgUQLIH1FwArKgbwCgBBKAXigEYAaKQgIXKgCZCBfQ4ADwAcB7AE4AXKAEsQQ4AIBmAQwDGwKAEkASsADOAYT4QIfEAUJQTQgJ49gALlgIUGLLgDc7Tr0EjzlqInUbSFEQmUCCyENZQGkIC4gDmLmxQAGQqfjp6Bi7c-MJQXkq+moyBxlCysRHgEABGUgnJqZrp+iAubjmeFgV+xAA2vUyF-lAAPj5+9G0A9ABUM8YzUFqyIADkItKisWBCYAJKfDtQABZ8AO55fGU8PL1mUBD38gYAJqJCogayA0JXQscHHY8HYAOkI7Q8eS6UFUfD4QgA8tUAFbAeRCAA8iCg3EkIBeGnGmlIKSG9AAfIMANrrLqrAC6OK4eIJtiQaEwOGQINIAH4icMbGSXFAZlNwdIwCB0Z9DAIpQAKACUViGfQGs1h8KRqPRWPJYqCJmeICiD1k-yYqAtxxB0l6cIECut-xBAhWL10ypmzCVUAA1FQRSZRNIoAqIDbyGQKPB2Q4uTy-UbgvtdgJDPgQmEIgAiaRw3O0fI2OP2Tm4HkcYKJYC9DRKFMmNN7TNlCo2SjMYtdUt2DmObn0asmDgcQgAN1kAigVwo8pAysIofDfBB+Wjsf7CcrxGTpWCUymsFOYF6LzKGg0kAOl6h3jVB5NGj4vWAIIdsQVa9C4T9R4xABaYCoGwAQ+EsYR7lWX9gFWKBPU0EJ4SZUQzQMe8lFWNV+lWdgcXrRsDxMI8T0Oc9L2vcJZzvDcySfAwXzfD8+C-NdymAf9jzAiCpHMKBVg4+DEMJEAUO4NCRAwjdsJ6XDXCAA);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the union a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions). To do this you need to add the `type` property, with the appropriate enum literal type to `TResA` and `TResB`:

```
export type TResA = {
   name: string;
   type: SYSTEM_TYPE.A;
} & IResCommon;
export type TResB = {
  age: number;
  type: SYSTEM_TYPE.B;
} & IResCommon;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAygmjAKgUQLIH1FwArKgbwCgBBKAXigEYAaKQgIXKgCZCBfQ4ADwAcB7AE4AXKAEsQQ4AIBmAQwDGwKAEkASsADOAYT4QIfEAUJQTQgJ49gALlgIUGLLgDc7Tr0EjzlqInUbSFEQmUCCyENZQGkIC4gDmLsFeEfBIaJg4yAB0xC5sUABkKn46egYu3PzCUEk+foyBxlCysRHgEABGUgnVFsl2aY5Z9LkFRZol+iAubpWevbWaxAA2S0y+i1AAPgsaw4SEAPQAVEfGR1BasiAA5CLSorFgQmACSnxPUAAWfADu1XxNHg8JZmKAQUHyAwAE1EQlEBlkqyEAKEnzeTx4T0y+wqHh63lUfD4QgA8u0AFbAeRCAA8iCg3EkIChGh2pEK612AD41gBtW69a4AXQZXCZLNsqQcGWyUAA-GyoDZOXsoEcDvtpGAQNT4YYBNqABQASisnOWq2OhOJZMp1LpXPVQRMkJAUTBslRTFQns+mWkSyJAkNPtRmQEVyhuhNR2YxqgAGoqN0xNIoIaIL7yGQKCl7OlcNl487gq9ngJDPgQmEIgAiaRE2u0JI2PMDGXEDjBPLAJYaJQlkxll6VpotGyUZjN3qt-rSwv0LsmDgcQgAN1kAigAIoBpAJsIojThr4mRqOdzc4LWWIxcawQOB1g3zASyhTQ0Gkgbw-+KU5vvV0ND4JZgEyQNYhPTJQnCeNHxpABaJCoGwAQ+EsYRQWuGDgGuKAo00EJiVFUR3QMP8oGuc0VmudgGT7Ad7xMR9n3eN8Py-cJt1-GoVUAgxgNA8C+Eg09mmAOCn1Q9CpHMSjxLwgjWRAYjuFIkRyJqKi-AtWiOCAA)

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think of that. Thank you so much.